# Raspberry Pi / MS SQL Server interaction

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm in the middle of a project that I can't test, so before I get too terribly entrenched in programming everything a certain way, I want to know if anyone is aware of compatibility issues I need to keep an eye out for.

These are the things I've been given, and can't be changed:
- A Windows XP machine (for now; they *promise* we'll upgrade to Windows 7 "soon") running MS SQL Server 2008
- A Raspberry Pi on the same network as the aforementioned computer, hooked up to a monitor

My task is to build a web page that will display realtime information based on the contents of the database.  The best way I've come up with to do this is to make a web page using PHP that uses SQL statements to analyze the data in the database, format it so it makes sense, and then display it in a relatively minimalistic format.  I never got a good answer about what browser it'll be displayed in, but I know they're leaving some newer build of Debian on the Pi, so I'm assuming it'll end up being something Chromium-based.

I've downloaded MS SQL Server, XAMPP, and the Microsoft SQL Server PHP drivers (not the MSSQL drivers that come with PHP).  I've managed to make something that's successfully pulling information off the server and updating it as necessary, but I'm starting to worry about the drivers, and any other configuration that might have to take place.  Should I be considering just scrapping the Microsoft functions and trying to make it work with the usual MSSQL stuff instead, or building something with PDO?  Is there anything special about running in a linux environment I should be aware of?  I won't really get the chance to test this on anything other than my windows laptop until "go time," so I want to be as prepared as possible.  I'd appreciate advice from anybody with any experience in this sort of project

Comment: I would recommend using PDO.  ODBC is also an option, and isn't too difficult to configure via `unixODBC` with the FreeTDS driver to talk to SQL Server.  A Raspberry Pi only costs $35 and running Debian on it is trivially easy.  Another no-cost option would be to run a Debian install in VirtualBox to familiarize yourself with hooking it up to SQL Server.

Comment: I liked the idea of playing around in a VirtualBox, however, I cannot for the life of me get it to see the SQL Server running on the host machine.  I set the host to a static IP address on a loopback adapter, and I can ping it from the virtualbox, but all my usual methods of connecting don't seem to work.  [this](http://davejamesmiller.com/blog/php-connecting-to-microsoft-sql-server-debian-ubuntu) looked so straightforward, it would've been perfect, except everything always just times out.  I've never played around with VirtualBox before; @Michael, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: So it sounds like your issue is getting SQL Server to listen for inbound TCP connections? The first step is to get SQL Server's ports open to the IP that your Vbox machine is bound to. After that, using freetds and tsql or isql and unixODBC to test connections is pretty easy to work out. Sort out the networking first though - I don't regularly work on Windows these days and haven't setup SQL Server in years so I'm afraid I can't help in any detail.

Answer (score 0):

> (...) but I know they're leaving some newer build of Debian on the Pi, so
>   I'm assuming it'll end up being something Chromium-based.

Regarding the browser, make sure your website is as light as possible (try not to use too much Javascript). Due to the device's limitations, browsing is rather slow, even with Midori (the default browser currently being shipped in the latest versions of Raspbian). You can install chromium but it'll be even slower.

As for the server, I agree with Michael Berkowski, go with PDO.